# Escape pipes in datatable in CucumberJS doesn't work

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

I'm trying to escape the pipes in my datatable but it only works for the first one

here's the content without escapes:

```
| name | address                   | phone number|
| John | 123 | Street Name | City  | 1234567890  |
```

here's with escapes:

```
| name | address                     | phone number|
| John | 123 \| Street Name \| City  | 1234567890  |
```

but when I use CucumberJS to use this table I got errors, which interprest above as `123 | Street Name \| City` , the second backslash doesn't work

anyone knows what the issue is? is that CucumberJS issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a known [issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/417) that should be fixed in a newer version.